# PayPal Android Integration - Login Process

Tags: android, paypal

I have successfully been able to integrate PayPal into an Android app, and get it working within my Sandbox account.

However, this means each and every time I want to make a payment, I have to at least go through the PayPal Confirm page.

Is there a way that once a user of the app logs into their PayPal account, that this Confirm page can be skipped?  Or, more to the point...  a user can click a "Pay with PayPal" button, and everything be handled automatically from that point?

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment.  The SDKs require at least two clicks (pay, [login if necessary,] confirm).  This is pretty standard among PayPal products.

We'll be releasing a feature shortly that offers an optional improvement to this.  Be on the lookout!